# strapi rest api request to change user role

Tags: json, request, strapi

I'm making following PUT request:

```
url: http://localhost:1337/api/users/3
payload: {
    "data": {
        "role": {
            "set": [{"id": 2}]
        }
    }
}
```

and for some reason it does not update the user role, I get full response however, the role Id remains 1. below is response im getting, any idea why it doesn't update the user role, and how to do it properly?

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "username": "czlenson",
    "email": "czlenson@stara.yo",
    "provider": "local",
    "confirmed": true,
    "blocked": false,
    "createdAt": "2023-04-13T19:46:40.331Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-04-13T20:15:24.804Z",
    "role": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Authenticated",
        "description": "Default role given to authenticated user.",
        "type": "authenticated",
        "createdAt": "2023-04-04T05:04:15.336Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-04-13T20:11:24.318Z"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this answer came a little late but you just need to send a payload like this:

```json
{
  "role": 2 #id of the role 
}
```

And don't forget to change the permissions to make this role change possible (via Strapi Admin) ️

The PUT request will also return the user info with its new role.

[Strapi Forum](https://forum.strapi.io/t/change-role-with-iap/484/2)